# Error interpreting query [update Student set Student.email=:email]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I'm using MySQL DataBase to learn Hibernate from video tutorial
i'm doing Step by step, and when i'm trying to execute query to update in dataBase on all records "Error interpreting query occurs". the wierd part is that the person who is executing the same query passess withouth any problem

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
     .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
     .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
     .buildSessionFactory();

     Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
     session.beginTransaction();

Query email = session.createQuery("UPDATE Student SET email=:email");
 email.setParameter("email", "code@gmail.com");
 email.executeUpdate();

 session.getTransaction().commit;
 session.close();

 }
```

I expect that all emails from dataBase will be updated but instead of     executing query i get

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [update Student set email=:email];
> this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser at org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.internal.SemanticQueryProducerImpl.interpret(SemanticQueryProducerImpl.java:66)

#### OK i found out what is the problem, i used hibernate-core 6Alpha release. I switched to 5.4.2.Final and everything is executing without any problems